# The podcast app is displaying the incorrect subscribed podcast

Tags: ios, podcasts

I am using the official Apple iOS podcast app.

A strange thing started happening 2 months back.

I have 5 podcasts that I subscribe to, one of them being the Joe Rogan Experience. One day the Joe Rogan podcast wasn't there anymore and a Christian podcast had taken its place *probably a sign*.

I unsubscribed from the Christian one, searched iTunes for the Joe Rogan podcast, and resubscribed. For a full day the app displayed the correct podcast but then magically changed back to the Christian one.

Now when I try unsubscribe and resubscribe, to the Joe Rogan podcast, it magically subscribes to / displays the "Intelligence Squared US debates" podcast. *I don't live in the US so this is probably not a sign*

I am using an iPhone (9.3.1) and podcast app (2.4)

If I download a different podcast player app (Overcast) and subscribe to the Joe Rogan experience it doesn't change to the random podcast. But the problem still remains in the apple podcast app.

I did a search and didn't find anyone else experiencing the same problem. Any ideas on what the problem could be or a possible solution?

Comment: There are no signs. Did you check the respective web sites of the podcasts for any information? Also, knowing whether it happened to anybody else wohn't help you to solve the problem. What exactly is your question?

Comment: @patrix I have edited the question. Please remove the hold and make it active.

Answer (score 1):

Note that all the podcasts getting mixed up are hosted on Libsyn. There appears to be an issue with certain international CDN's caching rss feeds incorrectly, or so say Libsyn. They have got to fix this issue once and for all. It's still happening to us in 2018.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different! Please refrain from adding comments in the Answer section, this is for answers to the questions. Once you have sufficient [reputation](http://apple.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you’ll be able to add [comments](http://apple.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment) and ask follow-up questions. To gain reputation, [answer questions that are clear and concise](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead).   - From Review

Answer (score 0):

I came across this question because I had the same issue, but since this question didn't have an answer at that time I asked it again [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/264878/random-podcasts-appeared-in-the-podcast-app). I kept fiddling with it and eventually found that, as I answered in my own question, "I'm not sure why this worked, but I reset my iPhone a second time and restored it from the same iCloud backup and that seems to have fixed it."

Just wanted to post the solution that worked for me in this question since it was one I came across while looking for a fix.

Answer (score -2):

I have had this happen on several occasions, the most recent being today.
Currently Welcome to Nightvale, Lore, History of Japan and 7 or 8 others have been replaced with Dada Land Radio....
It seems to happen when I download podcasts when I am abroad with a foreign SIM card.
Apple Support have been less than useless on every occasion I have contacted them.
Only fix I have found is to restore a backup... pain in the arse as I work on an oil rig and my backups are on my home computer!!
Good luck.