# Random podcasts appeared in the podcast app

Tags: ios, podcasts.app

I recently reset my iPhone and restored it using my latest iCloud backup. I noticed in the podcast app that four Christian podcasts appeared under a "Not Subscribed" section (seemed interesting that all of the podcasts had the same general theme). I had never subscribed to, or even heard of, the four podcasts. I deleted them and closed the podcast app. Now each time I reopen the podcast app, one of the podcasts continues to reappear and attempts to start downloading an episode.

I found [this question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/234539/the-podcast-app-is-displaying-the-incorrect-subscribed-podcast) that sounded oddly similar, but it had no answers.

**Update**

I tried removing all podcasts and syncing with iTunes on my computer (which shows no current podcast subscriptions), but this random podcast still appears.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure why this worked, but I reset my iPhone a **second time** and restored it from the **same** iCloud backup and that seems to have fixed it.

Comment: Please mark this as the best answer then